# Why doesn't Python get 1.bit_length()?

Tags: python

I am reading a book about Python and along I'm doing some experimentations on the interactive prompt.

During those experimentations I have noticed that if I code `1.bit_length()` (or any other type specific method) it doesn't work.

Yes, I know that the reason is that Python doesn't get the number and I need to type `(1).bit_length()`, but my question is: why? Why did they do so? I mean there are so many developers and they couldn't develop a parser that gets `1.bit_length()`?

Comment: `1 .bit_length()` also works.

Comment: Probably the same reason why you needed a space in `vector<Pair<int,int> >` in C++ for a long time: because the tokenizer returned `>>` as a single token, and it was hard to split in in a LALR(1) parsers.

Comment: `1.bit_length` is parsed as `1.` followed by `bit_length`. As `1.` is interpreted as a float, the following stuff is a syntax error (because there is no separator). In general, it works though: `1..hex()` correctly calls the `hex` method on the float `1.`.